# Generate secure form token in Java

Tags: java, token, csrf

What would be the algorithm to generate a form token against CSRF attack in Java? I know there is `java.security.SecureRandom` but does is guarantee acceptable number of collisions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`java.util.UUID`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) for this.

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
// ...
```

The algorithm is described in [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

Comment: Really? Why would you want to do that? The random part of a Java.util.UUID is relatively small.